# What does the $(function () ..) mean in this Bootstrap code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, web

I'm familiar with codes with forms like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {})
```

Or

```
(function(){})()
```

But I'm confused when I saw codes are like this

```
$(function () {
    $(".modal-link").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        $('#myModal').removeData("modal")
        $('#myModal').modal({remote: $(this).attr("href")}).css({
            'width': function () {
                return ($(document).width() * .9) + 'px';
            },
            'margin-left': function () {
                return -($(this).width() / 2);
            }
        });
    })
})
```

It seems that `$` is a jquery function, why should the function  be wrapped in this function? Is is the same as `$(document).ready(function() {})`?

Comment: [Yes, it is the same.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$(handlerFunction)` and `$(function() {})` have the same effect as `$(document).ready(handlerFunction)` and `$(document).ready(function() {})`. It's just a shortcut to save on typing.

As explained by [the doco](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).